# Xamarin Forms Android Action Bar remove but still have a big gap

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Forms to write my app and hit some problem in the layout in Android. I was trying to remove the Action Bar by editing the styles:

```
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

```
  <style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

However, there is a big gap between the content and status bar like below:
[image]

How can I fix it? Thanks!

**Updated with XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kapi.CustomViews"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Class="Kapi.Views.LoginPage">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="LoginPageBg.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <local:FacebookLoginButton Text="Facebook Login" Margin="20,0,20,40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Are you currently using a `NavigationPage`? If so, by using just a `ContentPage` you won't have the bar.  With this design though you also won't have a back button which can especially be a problem on iOS if this is a cross-platform app.  It looks like this is the first page in your app though, so maybe that isn't a big deal.

Comment: Is this a tabbed page?instead of Style setting could you share your Xaml / code beside code?

Comment: Please set the background color of the grid to red and see if the screen is filled with red or not. It could be the picture's size problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for displaying image

```
<Image Source="LoginPageBg.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```